# Writing a simple Invoice Total program and I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Tags: vb.net

Here's the code:

```
Public Class InvoiceTotalExpmt
    Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
        Dim discountPercent As Decimal
        If txtSubtotal.Text >= 500 Then
            discountPercent = 0.2
        ElseIf txtSubtotal.Text >= 250 And txtSubtotal.Text < 500 Then
            discountPercent = 0.15
        ElseIf txtSubtotal.Text >= 100 And txtSubtotal.Text < 250 Then
            discountPercent = 0.1
        Else
            discountPercent = 0
        End If

        Dim discountAmount As Decimal =
            txtSubtotal.Text * discountPercent
        Dim invoiceTotal As Decimal = txtSubtotal.Text - discountAmount

        txtDiscountPercent.Text = FormatPercent(discountPercent, 1)
        txtDiscountAmount.Text = FormatCurrency(discountAmount)
        txtTotal.Text = FormatCurrency(invoiceTotal)

        txtSubtotal.Select()

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I copied this example straight out of my textbook for practice, but the program won't run and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Please throw away any book that teaches you to compare `txtSubtotal.Text` to 500.

Comment: Hint: use the [numericupdown control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/numericupdown-control-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) instead of text boxes. And regarding formatting of the values: check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-set-the-format-for-the-windows-forms-numericupdown-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: Will the project really not run or does it run but not do what you expect? They are very different things. If it won't run then there must be at least one error message and you need to tell us what that is and where it occurs. If it will run but doesn't behave as expected then you need to explain exactly what behaviour you expect and exactly what behaviour you see. You also need to have used the debugger to step through your code line by line and examined the state at every step to see where reality differs from expectation BEFORE posting a question.

Comment: If you have simply copied that code and it doesn't work then it's up to you to make an effort to understand what it is supposed to be doing at least. You also need to be able to use the debugger so, if you don't already know that, stop what you're doing and learn now because that's an essential skill for all developers, regardless of skill/experience level.

Answer (score 1):

`Decimal` is a good choice for money. The `Text` property of a `TextBox` is a `String`. You cannot compare a `String` to a number. Turn on Options Strict in Project Properties and in Options for Visual Studio.

The `.TryParse` methods are very clever. They return `True` or `False` and if `True`, they fill in the second parameter with the converted value.

The `AndAlso` short circuits the `If`. If the first condition is false then the second condition is not evaluated. A tiny bit faster. Just a good habit where applicable.

The `D` following the literal values tells the compiler that this is a `Decimal` value not a `Double`.

Methods from the `Strings` class (`Strings` vs. `String`) are restricted to the vb.net library. Better to use the .net way. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings

I am afraid your book is a out-of-date.

```
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    Dim discountPercent As Decimal
    Dim Subtotal As Decimal
    If Not Decimal.TryParse(txtSubtotal.Text, Subtotal) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number in subtotal.")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Subtotal >= 500 Then
        discountPercent = 0.2D
    ElseIf Subtotal >= 250 AndAlso Subtotal < 500 Then
        discountPercent = 0.15D
    ElseIf Subtotal >= 100 AndAlso Subtotal < 250 Then
        discountPercent = 0.1D
    Else
        discountPercent = 0
    End If

    Dim discountAmount As Decimal = Subtotal * discountPercent
    Dim invoiceTotal As Decimal = Subtotal - discountAmount

    txtDiscountPercent.Text = discountPercent.ToString("P")
    txtDiscountAmount.Text = discountAmount.ToString("C2")
    txtTotal.Text = invoiceTotal.ToString("C2")

    txtSubtotal.Select()

End Sub
```